# How to extend types definition with custom types?

Tags: typescript, webpack, voximplant

I install [this types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/voximplant-websdk).
This file looks like [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/voximplant-websdk/index.d.ts).

But that types do not include some very helpfull types like **ClientState.** I want add to that types this enum:

```
 enum ClientState {
            DISCONNECTED,
            CONNECTING,
            CONNECTED,
            LOGGING_IN,
            LOGGED_IN,
        }
```

I wanna add this enum to *namespace VoxImplant*
How can I do it? 
My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./build_ts",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2016"
    ],
    "paths":{
      "*": [
        "*",
        "./types/*"
      ]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./app/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use d.ts from right [SDK npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/voximplant-websdk). It contains right d.ts.

Comment: I tried it, but d.ts declare modules like web-voximplant/Logger and my webpack did not resolve this path, when I try import it